# Post locally hosted wordpress site online

Tags: wordpress, web, host, vs-web-site-project, localserver

Can we upload a locally hosted wordpress site to any host or just the ones that support wordpress? I am using serverpress desktop-server to create wordpress sites locally, but I am really in a fix trying to find how I can publish them online.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack overflow :)

I think your question has been asked already, Please search on stack overflow to see if someone has asked the same question already to avoid getting your question down voted for being a duplicate.

Anyways here's what you gotta do...

Use https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

First, duplicate your site (you need to be an admin).

Then download zip file and `installer.php` and upload to your new host.

Then Create a new DB for your installation on your host.

Now assuming you uploaded to root of your site and your domain is example.com... head over to `example.com/installer.php`

Type in your db credentials and name (**Warning** Be careful with db name if you enter another pre existing DB it will be wiped out! ) details and domain related details.

It will take a 5 - 10 minutes or more depending on your site size and new servers speed.

Finally... You'll be presented with Success notice, check out the logs if you want to... Next thing you need to do is to login to your new site at `example.com/wp-admin` and save the permalinks page in settings to fix permalinks.

Voila! You just got your site migrated from localhost to a live server, Congrats!

Initial server doesn't have to be localhost you can follow same procedure to move your site from example1.com to example2.com...

Hope that helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can upload your locally hosted site to any server that satisfies the minimum requirements WordPress needs to work. Those requirements are given in the following link.
https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/